# How do I exit from a local host from my terminal

Tags: npm, terminal, localhost

After running a program using "npm run dev" on my inbuilt terminal in VsCode, I do not know how to exit connection between it and the local host. I have already tried [command + "." ] which works to exit out of nodemon, but am having no luck with my current application.

EDIT: I have a mac, and [control + "c"] doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `ctrl` + `C`.

Comment: Try this instead: Control + Z

Answer (score 0):

you can send `SIGINT` to npm by pressing `Ctrl+c`. This also works for most terminal applications and will exit out of them.